# Keep Visual Studio's output windows focussed on something other than build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to keep the 'Output' window of Visual Studio 2012 focussed on the 'Tests' output? Everytime I run my tests, my solution builds and the 'Output' window turns automatically to 'Build'. I have to manually select 'Tests' every time, which is becoming mildly anoying.

It feels like a silly question to ask, because it seems such a trivial thing. But searching for this didn't give me any answers, I not even found someone who was experiencing this same issue! I can't imagine I'm the only one who wants to use this kind of functionality

Comment: There is a related option, might affect this.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, General page.  Untick the "Show Output window when build starts".

Comment: what @HansPassant says: afaik there's no other way to disable changing focus to the output window. As an alternative you could dock the output or tests window somewhere else so that both occupy different space hence won't interfere with each other.

Comment: It is not the focus of the output window as a whole I´m looking for. That behaviour is exactly what I want. It´s the focus behaviour IN the output window that´s bugging me. Inside the output window you have the option ´Show output from´ that keeps changing to ´build´ instead of staying on ´Tests´ as I would like it to.

Comment: I was curious about the opposite. When I build, VS is on Build in the output window then switches to Tests. I was wondering how to keep it on build instead of tests.  Thanks Hans Passant - I actually had the Show Output window when buid starts unchecked, but checking it sounds useful so that it always appears when building.

Comment: This is especially nice to disable when you have JetBrains Resharper Build enabled (hopefully this comment might help someone find it via google, I always thought the issue would be a Resharper setting not a VS setting)

Comment: This also drives me crazy. Unticking "Show Output window when build starts" doesnt help. When I start debugging the Output window will always switch to "Show output from Debug" which I never want. I want it to always stay on "ASP.NET Core Webserver".

Comment: same here, I want to always stays on "ASP.NET Core Webserver" or just don't change it.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue too. I can’t even figure out how to tab to the “Show output from” dropdown which would be better than nothing…. Getting to the Output pane itself is ctrl+alt+o, but the build triggered by running tests always switches it to the Build output.

Comment: There’s a [developer community feedback issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/-/691460) which people should vote on! It’s not quite the same, but I agree with it—the automatic switch to Show output from: Tests should happen after the build succeeds (in addition to when you actually start the test run).