# Visual Studio Output window goes to "Show Output from: Build" when debugging

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.2

Seems something changed, I don't know what.
When I start debugging a solution the output window switches to "Build" automatically and then never switches to "Debug". I always have to switch it manually.

I have searched but no joy. How do I make Visual Studio go to "Debug" when debugging?

Comment: Does this still happen? This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19224478) where the user wanted to keep the Output window pointing to tests instead of switching to Build (due to running tests triggering builds). But for you it is probably something like a build is somehow being triggered after entering Debug mode which seems weird. You probably want the Build output to show up by default when building prior to debugging.

Comment: I just came here for the same question and problem. I don't remember it NOT switching back to debug after the build completed...